# WinRAR errors: "Cannot set [temp folder] as the current folder. Access is denied."

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, winrar

When I open up a zip file and try to drag the contents out to the desktop, I get these messages. I used to be able to do it all the time before I switched to Windows 8. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Note: I *am* able to just extract the contents in the same folder by clicking the 'extract' button.

`Cannot set C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DRa0.685 as the current folder. Access is denied.`

`Please check permissions of WinRAR folder for temporary files or specify another temporary folder in WinRAR settings.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try checking the access rights granted to the temp folder. I think, WinRar needs specific permissions(perhaps Modify) to be able to write.

This is this [link](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/729556-WinRAR-extracting-entire-temp-directory-with-drag-and-drop) which discusses a similar problem with the temp folders. It may help you.

I think that when you try to do a drag-and-drop to do an extract, WinRar uses the temp folder to complete the extraction and de-compression. Now since, the temp folder does not have Write/modify access to 'everyone' therefore this is failing. But when you do a right-click -> extract to, then you explicitly choose a folder where the write permission is already granted.

Do let me know if this works out.

Comment: Thank you. For those who need instructions: Right click on the Temp folder, go to the Security tab, click Advanced, and allow full control.

Answer (score 0):

go to options>settings>path  under it set the tempororary directory as any forlder other than in c: the problem will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You just go to %temp% then go back one path to Local path you will see Temp folder. Then right-click on temp folder > properties > securyty > edit > Make it full permission. Done!

Answer (score 0):

%temp% solution did not work for me. I had to open RAR. Then-option-setting-pat-browse-This Pc-Local Disk(C:)-Temp, click ok. Done. Reason %temp% wasn't working, because full control was already allowed, but that done nothing.